# CMake inherit static library dependency

Tags: cmake

I have a library that gets build and depends on other libraries:

```
add_library(library1 STATIC main.c)
target_link_libraries(library1 m;pthread)
```

If I want to now use the just declared `library1` in other library I would expect that `libm` and `libpthread` to be passed in the linker to build `library2`

```
    add_library(library2 STATIC main2.c)
    target_link_libraries(library2 library1) # I would expect m and pthread to be linked to library2 but don't
    add_executable(binary library2)
```

Is the normal behavior pass libm and libpthread  to the compiler to build `binary`?
Thanks

Comment: what happens if you use `library1 m pthread` instead of `library1 m;pthread`? [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) has an example similar to what you want. It seems strange that you can't link `m` and `pthread`.

Comment: Assuming lines `target_link_libraries(library1 m;pthread)`  and `target_link_libraries(library2 library1)` is processed by the **same** invocation of `cmake`, they would imply linking `library2` with `m` and `pthread` too. But if these lines are compiled by *different* `cmake` invocations, then `target_link_libraries(library2 library1)` links with a **library file**. Since the library file for the static library doesn't contain references to used libraries, `m` and `pthread` are not linked automatically. So, which case is yours?